# mui x datepickers - okText and cancelText not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.7" package.

```
<MobileDatePicker
    label="custom date"
    inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
    value={this.state.formData.date}
    okText="Confirm"
    cancelText="Close"        
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
 />
```

But I cannot change button labels by changing okText and cancelText props of MobileDatePicker component.

I suppose this issue ocurrs becuase this version is still an alpha version.

p.s:
I implemeted it by a javascript vanilla style solution. But it breaks react logic:

```
<MobileDatePicker 
   ...
   DialogProps={{ className: 'mui-datepicker' }}
   onOpen={this.handleOpen}
   ...
/>



handleOpen = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.mui-datepicker 
            .MuiDialogActions-root .MuiButton-root');
        btns[0].innerText = "Close";
        btns[1].innerText = "Confirm";
    })
}
```

Is there a way to overcome this issue, rather than using js solution?

Comment: Where did you see these `okText` and `cancleText` props? Neither of them is mentioned in the documentation of `MobileDatePicker` - https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/mobile-date-picker/

Comment: You're correct. The intellisense showed me these props exist. Probably this is a mistake. So How can I change cancel & ok lables (excpet js vanilla). Any idea?

Comment: I don't think that is possible given the current API. You just want to change the text of the buttons from `ok` and `cancel` to `Close` and `Confirm`?

Comment: No. I want to change it to something in non-english language, to fit my app. But, nevermind, it's not a critical issue.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you - https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/

Comment: I've already localized the MobileDatePicker, and all the modal objects have been localized excpet the action buttons. I assume this happens, since it is an alpha version.